# Android - How can I show file type icon in a file list?

Tags: java, android, listview, android-arrayadapter

I'm loading the contents of a directory into a list and beside the filename I want to have an icon for that file type, 5 possible types. I've seen examples for adding icons to lists for strings but not dynamic data. How can I modify my code below to add icons? I've saved the files in drawable-hdpi.

```
private void getFiles(File[] files){
            items = new ArrayList<String>();
            items.add(getString(R.string.goto_root));
            for(File file : files){
                String filename = file.getName().toString();
                String filenameArray[] = filename.split("\\.");
                String extension = filenameArray[filenameArray.length-1];
                Log.d("Extension", extension);
                items.add(file.getPath());
            }
            ArrayAdapter<String> fileList = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,R.layout.list_item, items);
            setListAdapter(fileList);
        }

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView android:id="@+id/row"
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>
```